# Clean out external Facebook links when copying

Tags: browser-addons, facebook

When posting links on Facebook, it adds strange characters to these links.

For example:

This link on Facebook:

> http://www.facebook.com/l.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.playmapscube.com%2F&h=PAQGY9D2_AQErxFAYpmWE5ZvnwYgQ5kq1DbNfnxZ4KA35Ng&enc=AZO6znTkrhTxtcajizGh8PBYTfiE7kRzoCHzIZ2tGFHN9hs4gRjfvg-LSQ_wCk2mH22modqAPkG5IRtrTMmHNnVA

Will be redirected to this:

> http://www.playmapscube.com

So, is there any way (Chrome extension/Firefox addon/Greasemonkey script...) to clean out these strange characters when copying links on Facebook?

Comment: It is definitely possible, but not sure how.

Comment: I've found a userscript called Facebook Direct Links (http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/126898) and it works great.

Comment: just post it as the answer.

Comment: @Mark If you found a solution you should put in an answer explaining about what you found and how it worked for you. :)